# Xna Reset Sprite Effect to default

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, sprite

I draw all my sprites using Immediate mode.

```
mSpriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, null, SamplerState.LinearWrap, null, null);
foreach(UIWidget widget in widgets) {
    widget.Draw(mSpriteBatch);
}
mSpriteBatch.End();
```

In one of the sprites I apply custom effect:

```
     public override void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) {

     effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
     spriteBatch.Draw(
         texture,
         position,
         source,
         color,
         rotation,
         origin,
         scale * Globals.ScreenScaleFactor,
         SpriteEffects.None,
         depth);
 }
```

Due to to this all sprites that are drawn after have this effect applied. How can I "discard" this effect?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of applying the custom effect directly, it is conventional to pass the effect into the call of [SpriteBatch.Begin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433700.aspx).

This means ending the previous `mSpriteBatch` and starting a new one with custom effect and ending that one and starting a new one to discard the custom effect. This should not cause any performance implications as you are already using `SpriteSortMode.Immediate` which renders each UIWidget separately.

You could also use a separate `SpriteBatch` for custom effect.